# How do I Block Windows 11 upgrade without blocking windows 10 feature updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry

I have created the following registry keys:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v TargetReleaseVersion /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate /v TargetReleaseVersionInfo /t REG_SZ /d 21H2
```

But this in turn will block any windows 10 feature updates. Is there any way to keep windows 10 updates but block windows 11 upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

According to  [Can I stop auto upgrade to Windows 11?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-11/can-i-stop-auto-upgrade-to-windows-11/m-p/2776338)

You probably just want to set `ProductVersion` in that registry area.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]  
"TargetReleaseVersion"=dword:00000001
"TargetReleaseVersionInfo"="21H1"
"ProductVersion"="Windows 10"
```

If nothing else you can simply update `TargetReleaseVersionInfo` as and when new versions come out. The list of editions supported by Microsoft is at https://aka.ms/WindowsTargetVersioninfo

Some more informatio on the relevant keys at https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.WindowsUpdate::TargetReleaseVersion

Comment: Either way, is it a matter of always having to update users registry keys to contain the latest windows 10 feature update? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to block a Windows 11 upgrade is to not meet one if its arbitrary and unnecessary requirements; [Disabling secure boot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/disabling-secure-boot?view=windows-11) in your BIOS currently blocks it from upgrading.

When you go to do Windows 10 updates (manually) you'll see this message:

> This PC doesn't currently meet the minimum requirements to run Windows
> 11

[image]

Perfect! You still get all the Windows 10 updates, with no fear of it auto-upgrading to Windows 11.

Turning off secure boot also makes it easier to boot from USBs like Live Linux ISOs and other [bootable utilities](https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/5_bootable_isos_to_boot_and_repair_your_computer_for_free.html).