# Which version is "22H2" in order to use it for TargetReleaseVersion?

Tags: windows

One can block Windows updates using the registry and declaring the targetversion for example like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"TargetReleaseVersion"=dword:00000001
"TargetReleaseVersionInfo"="2004"
```

I want to update my Windows 11 version to 22H2, and then block any further updates.

Which version number should I use for "TargetReleaseVersion" and for "TargetReleaseVersionInfo" in this case?

Comment: If this is a consumer machine (yours and not a company machine), you cannot block updates.  Windows 11 has 4 more years of feature updates to come. To the extent you try a registry change, Microsoft just goes around it.

Comment: Aside from what @John says... did you check the [List of Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) on Wikipedia?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1699279/how-do-i-block-windows-11-upgrade-without-blocking-windows-10-feature-updates

Answer (score -1):

```
"TargetReleaseVersion"=dword:00000001
"TargetReleaseVersionInfo"="22H2"
```